# How do I mount sdc disk to /dev/sda2 on CentOS

Tags: centos, mount

As per my screenshot, I only have 30G on /dev/sda2. It won't be enough as I will be running the test on large dataset, therefore I need to mount sdc disk (200G) to /dev/sda2 to have more space. Could you please let me know the command to do this? I was going to try a program like gparted but I don't have a graphic card since this is the VM on Azure cloud. Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: Saying 'mount `sdc` to `sda2`' suggests you don't fully understand what you want. `/dev/sda2` is your root file system, and replacing or migrating that is tricky. In your case, you probably want to just partition `sdc` (or `mkfs` it directly) and mount it somewhere, and point your application to it.

Comment: Hello @Halfgaar thank you very much for your reply. If you are right, I am quite new to Linux OS, I have never partitioned Linux hard disk before therefore I wasn't sure. I would follow your suggestion to partition sdc, in this case, could you please recommend me a correct command to do this please?

Comment: Personally, I maybe would not even partition it, but just run `mkfs.ext4` (if you want `ext4`) on it directly: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc` (disclaimer: be sure you want to overwrite data on it!!!). Then you can put it in your `/etc/fstab` and mount it. You may want to read some articles about mounting volumes first. And perhaps also about using `fdisk`, if you still want to partition.

Comment: @Halfgaar ok thank you very much for your recommendation.